# C++ Binary Search function does not print

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, binary-search

Could anyone help me to fix this code? The main does fill an array of 1000 random numbers from 1 to 1000, and when it goes into the function it sorts in ascending order and it follows a Binary Search, but the problem is that it does not print out anything.

```
int f10(int array[], int size)
{
    int temp; // temporary swap variable 
    cout << "Ascending Order:" << endl;
    for (int x = 1; x <= size; x++)
    { //how times 

        for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++)
        {

            if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
            {

                //we need to swap
                temp = array[j]; //temp is holding the first value 
                array[j] = array[j + 1]; //
                array[j + 1] = temp; //temp holds the second value
            }
        }
    }
    for (int x = 1; x <= size; x++)
    {
        cout << array[x] << ", ";
    }

    int value;
    cout << "\nGimme a number to search:\n\t";
    cin >> value;

    int left = array[1], right = array[1000];
    while (left < right)
    {

        int middle = (left + right) / 2;
        if (array[middle] == value)
        {
            return middle;
        }
        else if (array[middle] > value)
        {
            right = middle - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            left = middle + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I can’t compile images.

Comment: Array indexes start at 0.

Comment: If it really doesn’t print anything (even  "Ascending Order:") then you don’t call it or it’s windows and not a console application.

Comment: it does print all numbers, but when the user input the number to search it does not print out anything.

Comment: Hi, please cleanup the indentation of your code sample.

Comment: Then correct your question!

Comment: How should it print anything after `cout << "\nGimme a number to search:\n\t";`?

Comment: Missing a couple includes in there and and a `using namespace std;`. Try to get out of that `using namespace std;` habit. It can cause problems.

Comment: You probably want to use `int left = 1, right = 1000;` instead of `int left = array[1], right = array[1000];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were few bugs in your code. Check this one. Doing it only for 10 numbers. Make it for 1000 or whatever you prefer by writing your random number logic.

```
#include <iostream>
int f10(int arr[],int size);
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {22,53,14,11,75,6,7,1,8,88};
    int result_index;
    result_index = f10(arr,10);
    cout << "Result = "<<result_index<<endl;    
}
int f10(int array[], int size) {
    int temp; // temporary swap variable 
    cout << "Default Array:" << endl;
    for (int x=0; x < size; x++)
    {
        cout<< array[x]<<", ";
    }
    cout << "Ascending Order:" << endl;
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++){  

        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {

            if(j != size-1 && array[j] > array[j+1]) {  // Major Change

                // Swapping
                temp = array[j]; //temp is holding the first value 
                array[j] = array[j+1]; //
                array[j+1] = temp; //temp holds the second value
            }
        }      
    }
    for (int x=0; x < size; x++)
    {
        cout<< array[x]<<", ";
    }

    int value;
    cout <<"\nGimme a number to search:\n\t";
    cin >> value;

    int left = 0, right = 9; // Major change
    while (left <= right){ // Major change

        int middle = (left + right) / 2;
        if (array[middle] == value)
        {
            return middle;
        }
        else if (array[middle] > value)
        {
            right = middle - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            left = middle + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;

}
```